# Slow query for join tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to optimize the following query:

There are two tables, `Post` (>1 million records) and `Category` (around 10-20 records).

The query should retrieve all `posts` which have a `category_id` of 1 and 2. There is an index for the join table `posts_categories` for both the `post_id` and `category_id` and the explain statement confirms that the index is being used in the query.

However, the query is still slow. It seems like the grouping is the cause here.

Appreciate some advice on improving it.

```
Post
   .joins(:categories)
   .where(categories: { id: [1,2] })
   .group(:post_id) 
   .having("COUNT(categories.id) = 2")
```

```
 SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts` 
   INNER JOIN `posts_categories` ON `posts_categories`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id` 
   INNER JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `posts_categories`.`category_id` 
   WHERE `categories`.`id` IN (1, 2) 
   GROUP BY `post_id` 
   HAVING (COUNT(categories.id)=2)
```

Comment: You could improve this question by calling `to_sql` on your query code and displaying the generated SQL on the question.

Comment: Could I ask what the purpose of the query is? It looks like you want to find all the posts which are either in category 1 or 2, and which have two categories... Are you trying to find out which posts are in both categories 1 and 2?

Comment: Also, just thinking aloud. Are there indexes on POSTS_CATEGORIES.POST_ID and POSTS_CATEGORIES.CATEGORY_ID?

Comment: The query will return posts in category 1 and 2. Yes, there are indexes on post_id, category_id and a composite index of both.

Answer (score 3):

This might not work, but it's worth a try.

You could try writing a sub-query to get the category ids.

You'd need to write a simple ActiveRecord model on your PostsCategories join table...

```rb
Post
  .where(id: PostCategory.where(category_id: [1,2]).select(:post_id))
  .joins(:post_categories)
  .group(:post_id) 
  .having("COUNT(post_category.category_id)=2")
```

So, the advantages here:

- You're no longer joining to the large 'categories' table via the join table.
- The subquery lets the database select only the PostCategories with those categories ids, narrowing that field.

Comment: Would `pluck(:post_id)` be better as it doesn't convert a database query result into a Ruby array without constructing an ActiveRecord object as `select` does?

Comment: @MikeHeft I'm afraid you've got that backwards. `pluck` will return the values as a ruby array. `select` constructs an SQL query with those columns in the select list. Try this: `User.select(:id).to_sql`. Changing that to pluck will return an error. Using the select method in the where call will convert it to a single SQL statement with a subquery.

Comment: Bah you're right :P lol. But still, wouldn't pluck be a little more performant since it doesn't create the ActiveRecord object? Since pluck just return an array of the values, where select returns an ActiveRecord::Relation

Comment: @MikeHeft It'll return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, and not AR objects unless you call `all` or an enumerable method. Noting that POSTS has more than a million rows, I'd assume that CATEGORIES_POSTS has more than that. Plucking all of those would lead to a massive array in memory, and probably a long enough SQL statement to overflow (oracle, for instance, can only have 1,000 items in a list).

Comment: Gotcha! Didn't think of the size of the array :D Thanks for that insight :D I'm always looking for more performant queries. Even tho it's not my question up there, thanks for the fast replies :D

Comment: @MikeHeft No problems. I'm glad you found it interesting. Unfortunately I learned that technique through quite a lot of painful tuning work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried your approach but unfortunately the query speed hasn't improved.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, another thing to try out.

I'm not sure if you can write this in ActiveRecord, and it's pretty complex to convert it to pure AREL, so here's a work-around which might help you out.

```rb
Post.find_by_sql(
  "
    select * from posts where id in (
      SELECT cp1.post_id FROM JOIN categories_posts cp1
      INNER JOIN categories_posts cp2 ON cp1.post_id = cp2.post_id
      where cp1.category_id = 1 and cp2.category_id = 2
    )
  "
)
```

The other thing to consider would be paging, you could try adding something like this to only look at a section of your posts:

```
and cp1.post_id between 1 and 10000
```

(Tested on Oracle, there may be some syntax differences)